# CodeIgniter - Routing urls with GET Variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-3

I checked the similar questions out there, but those doesnt seem to help.

I have an email verification like, that is to be routed in CodeIgniter to the right function with data passed to the function for further processing.

Sample URL :

```
http://mysite.dev/verify/?id=emailaddress@gmail.com&hash=562828a975740ac6820e40f7f61b4407
```

Current Route :

`$route['verify/(:any)'] = 'formcontroller/verification/$1';`

Function :

```
public function verification($slug)
    {
        parse_str(parse_url($slug, PHP_URL_QUERY), $fileds);
        var_dump($fields);
    }
```

The problem is, I get a 404 when I try the url listed above. I get `Message: Undefined variable: fields` when I try something like `http://amazon.dev/verify/asdasdasd`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**ADD : If there is no `?` in the url, it works. But for the standard of a get query url should be, I would like like to know how to solve this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually was, the query started after a `/`.

Actually the url should be in this model, `?` immediately after the directory name.

```
http://mysite.dev/verify/?id=emailaddress@gmail.com&hash=562828a975740ac6820e40f7f61b4407
```

Route should be

```
$route['verify'] = 'formcontroller/verification';
```

And the variables should be handled using `get` method of `CodeIgniter`.

`$this->input->get('variablename');`

Also, the url should be `urlencoded` just incase if there are any characters which are not exclusively allowed by the config file.

Answer (score 2):

Route doesn't receive query string as i understand. So, you should get variable from GET array. For this, 1st test that in config.php set

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
```

then in controller:

```
public function verification($slug)
    {
    $fields['id'] = $this->input->get('id');
    $fields['hash'] = $this->input->get('hash');
    var_dump($fields);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the path segment of the URL is routable, and you don't need to parse the query parameters ...

Access them via the `$_GET` superglobal (like in raw PHP) or via the [Input class' get() method](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get).

Comment: Access them via `$_GET` in the controller function? How do I route the url so that the function is called? Currently, because of the `?` the routing doesnt work.

Comment: There's a tutorial in the official documentation that is half-focused on routing ...

Answer (score 0):

the `?` is not a permitted character in the URI segment in

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
```

which is located in application/config/config.php

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-';
```

you can append the ? to the list

here is a list of url encoded characters
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Answer (score 0):

Config.php

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=';`